# Correct way of using TYPE REF TO data?

Tags: abap, assignment-operator

I've declared a type with the type of ref to data. so it looks like this

```
my_type type ref to data.
```

Then I declare an internal table, which I want to assign to my_type.

```
Data:
  ref_data type my_type.
  itable type it_table.

ref_data = itable.
```

Why can't I assign itable to ref_data, isn't a ref to data is a generic data type and can be assigned to anything?

Answer (score 4):

This is very similar to other programming languages, and it's not a problem of typing the variables or references. You're trying to assign a value to a pointer variable - that won't work anywhere. You need to use [GET REFERENCE OF itable INTO ref_data](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abapget_reference.htm).

Answer (score 2):

That's not quite how a data reference works.  A data reference has to be typed, but you type it at run time.

```
data: ref_data type ref to data.
data: itable type it_table.

"you access the data in a data reference via a field symbol
field-symbols: <dref> type any.  

create data ref_data type it_table.

assign ref_data->* to <dref>.

<dref> = itable.
```

I now have a copy of itable in my dynamically typed variable ref_data, accessed by the field symbol .

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the reference to your structure:

```
DATA itable TYPE it_table.
DATA my_type TYPE REF TO data.

GET REFERENCE OF itable INTO my_type.
```

Comment: Isn't that the same thing @vwegert suggested 11 years ago?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Philipp, maybe, but more detailed. vwegert didn't declare any variable...